# Data dictionary file for database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a data dictionary that lists all the tables, columns and data types in PDF file format. I use SQL Server 2008 R2. How do I get this information?

I was able to view the schema view as someone suggested with all the information I need, but how to make a PDF file format with that information?

Comment: Look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx.

Comment: I did but how can I export it to pdf?

Comment: You use some tool like Microsoft Word that will create PDF formats.

Comment: That does not answer my question because if I could create a word document I would not ask to help me create a PDF file. What I am asking in other words is how to export the data from the view in SQL server?

Comment: Just copy paste-it. More work, indeed. If you don't like this, then first export it to Excel and then convert it to PDF.

Comment: Thanks I did something similar

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using a paid product for what you're looking for, http://www.sqldatadictionary.com/ , http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.aspx , or http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/ ..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dataedo](http://dataedo.com) if you looking for tool with gui. Has free version. Program semi-automatically generates the database schema and then can export schema to pdf or html format. It worked for me.

Comment: Very good tool. I just trialled it on a large SQL Server DB and it produces great results.

Answer (score 1):

Best file result when used MS Access data documenter do it for you. I first used a tool to convert MS SQL db to MS Access db. Then I used data documenter tool within MS Access.

Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

look at the

```
SELECT      *
FROM        SYS.OBJECTS A
LEFT JOIN   SYS.COLUMNS B ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID
WHERE       A.TYPE_DESC = 'USER_TABLE'
```

and select your specific columns